# How to adjust Python's sys.argv to change its length accordingly

Tags: python, if-statement, arguments, parameter-passing, index-error

I've been attempting to make the sys.argv[] to either change its output according to the number of argument that the user input. I am trying to make it so that if there is no sys.argv[5] then it would use sys.argv[4]. Currently I have tried both this ideas with my problem always **IndexError: list index out of range** when I do attempt to make sys.argv[5] left empty:

```
if len(sys.argv) is 4:
    location = int(sys.argv[1])
    order = sys.argv[2]
    amount = sys.argv[3]
    user = sys.argv[4]
    company= sys.argv[4]
    print(company)
else:
    location = int(sys.argv[1])
    order = sys.argv[2]
    amount = sys.argv[3]
    user = sys.argv[4]
    company= sys.argv[5]
    print(company)
```

also attempted to change **"if len(sys.argv) is 4:"** with **"if sys.argv[5] != True:"**. I've read some posting about solving the index but just don't know how to actually tailor the code for my own use.

Thanks!

Comment: Lists indexes start at zero, if `len(sys.argv) == 4` then the first index is `0` and the last index is `3`

Comment: Why are you using `is`?

Comment: Yeah, I just found out that the index was actually 5 not just 4 @lain Shelvington.

Comment: Should I use "==" @klutt? I was wondering about it as I was using 'is' often and it still works.

Comment: @Mythorim What you should do is to read about what both do. Using `is` here is a very strange thing.

Comment: @klutt You're right, "==" is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try/except` block like below, where if `index 5` is present use it, else use `index 4`.

```
if len(sys.argv) >= 4:
    location = int(sys.argv[1])
    order = sys.argv[2]
    amount = sys.argv[3]
    user = sys.argv[4]
    try:
        company= sys.argv[5]
    except IndexError:
        company= sys.argv[4]
    print(company)
else:
    print('Provide minimum 4 args')
```